# How to inner join two other inner join queries

Tags: mysql

my first post, so hopefully I am clear.
I have a table "testpd5" with daily entries for multiple printer serial numbers with page counts.
I need to find the associated page count per serial number for the first and last entry of every month.

I wrote one query to find the first date (from datetime stamp) of the month then use that date to find the associated records info. This works fine.

Then I did the same for the last date of the month.
Note that every serial number may not have the same first and last date.

My issue is am I trying to inner join these two min and max queries so that the record set will show the serial number and min and max dates and page counts,
but I cannot join these two min and max queries.
Greatly appreciate some help.

Here is the code;

```
SELECT
ma.PageCount,
m.PageCount,
m.sn,
m.MinDate,
m.Name,
m.ID,
ma.ID

FROM

-- min query

(
(SELECT 
MIN(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS MinDate,
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS minMonthNo,
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS minYearNo,
SerialNumber AS sn,
ID,
Name,
PageCount

FROM
testpd5
WHERE Customer = 97
GROUP BY sn, minMonthNo, minYearNo 
ORDER BY sn, minYearNo DESC, minMonthNo DESC
) AS m

INNER JOIN

(SELECT 
PageCount,
SerialNumber AS sn,
ID,
STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') AS RecDate,
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS MonthNo,
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS YearNo
FROM testpd5
WHERE Customer = 97 
) AS r

WHERE r.RecDate = m.MinDate
ORDER BY sn, minYearNo DESC, minMonthNo DESC
ON m.sn = r.sn AND m.minMonthNo =r.MonthNo AND m.minYearNo = r.YearNo
) AS A
-- end of min query

JOIN

-- max query

(
(SELECT 
MAX(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS Date,
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS MonthNo,
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS YearNo,
SerialNumber AS sn,
PageCount,
ID

FROM
testpd5
WHERE Customer = 97
GROUP BY sn, MonthNo, YearNo 
ORDER BY sn, YearNo DESC, MonthNo DESC
) AS ma

INNER JOIN

(SELECT 
PageCount,
SerialNumber AS sn,
ID,
STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') AS RecDate,
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS MonthNo,
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(LastScanDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) AS YearNo,
Name
FROM testpd5
WHERE Customer = 97 
) AS r1

WHERE r1.RecDate = m.MinDate
ORDER BY sn, YearNo DESC, MonthNo DESC
ON ma.sn = r1.sn AND ma.MonthNo =r1.MonthNo AND ma.YearNo = r1.YearNo
) AS B
-- END OF MAX query

ON m.SerialNumber = ma.SerialNumber AND m.MonthNo  = ma.MonthNo AND m.YearNo = ma.YearNo
```

Comment: Can you add info on this: "but I cannot join these two min and max queries." Why is it that you cannot do that?

Comment: Normally the ON-clause should be like this ` SELECT .. FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table1.id WHERE ....` You have done it different in your sql.

Comment: Luuk, thanks for responding. I meant that I get an error. basically, I have two derived tables  r & m that I called A and I want to join them to derived tables r1 & ma that I called B, so ultimately, I wish to join  A & B

Comment: @Luuk I changed the order and put the On calsue before teh where clause but still get errors

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you provide a minimum reproducible example your odds of getting the response you want are increased. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Without the error, and without data, and without the table definitions (DDL), it is hard to tell what i going wrong. That's why a "minimum reproducible example" is asked ...

Comment: @Eric_DB: "I changed the order and put the On clause...." use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64848375/edit) to also change your question. Because now it is unclear what your are really doing (after the change), and it is also unclear what error you have